# jquery draggable for multiple divisions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The Drag works properly in the first division but is not working properly in the next one. I need to get it working without changing the div Id/Class name.

Fiddle here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daneuchar/zHyA9/23/)

HTML:

```
<div class="track">
    <div id="rocket">    
    </div>
</div>
<br><br><div style="clear:both">
<div class="track">
    <div id="rocket">    
    </div>
</div>

​
```

CSS:

```
.track {
    height: 400px;
    width: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    float:left;
    background: #ccc;
}
#rocket{
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Symbolicons_Transportation/48/Rocket.png');
    position:relative;
    top:352px;
}
​
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.track').each(function(){


    //rocket drag
    $(this).children("#rocket").draggable({
        containment: ".track",
        axis: "y",
        scroll: false,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            draggingRocket = true;
        },
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            // Show the current dragged position of image


        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            draggingRocket = false;
        }
    });
    });
});​
```

Comment: First - you must change ID for rocket divs. ID must be unique. Use class instead of ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zHyA9/30/

1. id should always be unique... so changed your ids to class
2. added  `containment: $(this),` in your draggable class

Comment: or in 2) simply use `containment:"parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some thing in html code.

```
<div class="track">
<div id="rocket">    
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
<div class="track">
<div id="rocket">    
</div>
</div>
```

Here the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sselvamani22/zHyA9/27/)

Comment: it works in your case, but that is just because of changed layout that masked another bug (wrong `containment` set). And changin a layout is not what OP wants I guess

Answer (score 0):

You need several changes in your `html` as well as `js` code.

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHyA9/26/).

JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.track').live("hover",function(){

```
//rocket drag
$(this).children(".rocket").draggable({
    containment: this,
    axis: "y",
    scroll: false,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        draggingRocket = true;
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        // Show the current dragged position of image


    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        draggingRocket = false;
    }
});
});
```

});​